# Open several dependent functions in matlab with scripting

Tags: matlab

I have several matlab functions and one script that call those functions.  Suppose that they are 'a.m' 'f1.m' 'f2.m' and 'f3.m'. The script 'a.m' must open the functions files when it is manually opened and the run command is used. How can I do that with scripting techniques?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. What prevents you from making them all functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean "open the functions for editing".

```
edit
```

is actually a function:

```
edit(varargin)
```

So the script can either have a line

```
edit f1.m f2.m f3.m
```

or can programatically construct a cell array of strings

```
cstrFunctions = {'f1.m' 'f2.m' 'f3.m'}
edit(cstrFunctions{:});
```

Comment: This is what I was asking. I had some trouble searching for this. Thanks. If they are already opened how can I prevent it from being opened again within a cycle?